# file_get_contents from url that is only accessible after log-in to website

Tags: php, authentication, session, curl, file-get-contents

I would like to make a php script that can capture a page from a website. Think *file_get_contents($url)*.

However, this website requires that you fill in a username/password log-in form before you can access any page. I imagine that once logged-in, the website sends your browser an authentication cookie and with every consequent browser request, the session info is passed back to the website to authenticate access.

I want to know how i can simulate this behavior of the browser with a php script in order to gain access and capture a page from this website.

More specifically, my questions are:

1. How do I send a request that
   contains my log-in details so that
   the website replies with the session
   information/cookie
2. How do i read the session
   information/cookie
3. How do i pass back this session
   information with every consequent
   request (*file_get_contents*, *curl*) to
   the website.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Curl is pretty well suited to do it. You don't need to do anything special other than set the `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` options. Once you've logged in by passing the form fields from the site the cookie will be saved and Curl will use that same cookie for subsequent requests automatically as the example below illustrates.

Note that the function below saves the cookies to `cookies/cookie.txt` so make sure that directory/file exists and can be written to.

```
$loginUrl = 'http://example.com/login'; //action from the login form
$loginFields = array('username'=>'user', 'password'=>'pass'); //login form field names and values
$remotePageUrl = 'http://example.com/remotepage.html'; //url of the page you want to save  

$login = getUrl($loginUrl, 'post', $loginFields); //login to the site

$remotePage = getUrl($remotePageUrl); //get the remote page

function getUrl($url, $method='', $vars='') {
    $ch = curl_init();
    if ($method == 'post') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies/cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies/cookies.txt');
    $buffer = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $buffer;
}
```

Comment: This still works great for me. If it's not working for you then check that a) you have provided all the required form fields, and b) your cookies.txt file is writable.

Comment: Tip : look carefully if the form contains hidden fields that can be required to log in.

Comment: This method no longer works. 1) They require a captcha field now when they detect that you're trying to login with this method. 2) The form names and details have changed.

Answer (score 0):

The [http pecl extension](http://de.php.net/http) can do it, also [PEAR::HTTP_Client](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Client), [Snoopy](http://snoopy.sourceforge.net/) and many many other libraries/classes.
If you (for whatever reason) you want to achieved this with `file_get_contents`, you can use the [stream context options for the http wrapper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) to set POST and cookie parameters and [stream_get_meta_data](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php) to read the response headers including the cookies.