# file_get_contents from behind a login protected age

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Wondering if its possible to get information from a page that is behind a login screen / admin area using file_get_contents. I have a userid / password, of course.

Thanks to all.

Comment: You can use `cUrl` to login first and on succes continue with the `file_get_contents()` of the file you need to get. You will need to be logged in first, because the `file_get_contents` of a page will check login first. You would get the HTML of the login page if you are not logged in.

Comment: Before people starts their random negative voting, I think I have got the reply to my question from a previous thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082302/file-get-contents-from-url-that-is-only-accessible-after-log-in-to-website

Comment: Well my answer is pointing you into the right direction right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082302/file-get-contents-from-url-that-is-only-accessible-after-log-in-to-website

Comment: For some reason this is not working for me, I am getting redirected to the login page when I do `echo $remotePage;` If I don't write that line, I get a all-white page. cookies fielder is there and cookies/cookie.txt is also getting created.

Any tips ?