# PHP: file_get_contents not giving me output I expect :(

Tags: php, file-get-contents

This is my pretty simple code:

```
session_name("miz");
session_start();
include_once 'codeFragments/sessions.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    header('Location: login.php?e=1');
    exit;
}

//include('simple_html_dom.php');

$homepage = file_get_contents('http://localhost:8888/Ryan/Mart/1/cPanel.php?p=create_member');


echo $homepage;exit;
```

The problem is, I always get the contents of the login.php pages instead of getting the contents of cPanel.php, even though I am logged in.

And when I try this:
    `$homepage = file_get_contents('cPanel.php?p=create_member');`

it says: failed to open stream: **No such file or directory**

What the heck am I doing wrong? I have double checked, this file is in the same directory as the cPanel.php file.

Comment: What's with the neg votes?

Comment: I guess the negative votes are telling you to [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-get-contents.php).

Comment: Since the file you are calling is obviously returning something wrong, we need that files content.

Comment: @RolandoIsidoro The FM doesn't help though.

Comment: Your example shows: You have no plan about all technologies used in your script (including PHP). Basically this is no problem since this is a Q/A site. The problem is what your example *doesn't* show: Information required to solve the problem. That's why `-1`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol it helps on the **No such file or directory** error part. As for the logic he wants to implement your right, your answer below might is more helpful.

Comment: @hek2mgl All the information needed is provided. All it takes is some basic experience with server connectivity to understand.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol ... meaning I don't have a basic understanding of this technologies? OK

Comment: Rolando, which part? I did RTFM. @hek2mgl, what more could you possibly need for this simple problem? All you need is pretty much given and Niet the Dark Absol got why I was having that problem.

Comment: @hek2mgl I didn't say understanding, I said experience ;) Yes, I've tried having the server pretend to be me when accessing things before. This gave me experience.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I still miss relevant information but since you found an answer quickly you are probably right.. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You* might be logged in, but it's not *you* accessing the "remote" file; your server is. And your server isn't logged in.

Rather than using `file_get_contents`, consider using cURL (although personally I would go all out and send a manual HTTP request!) and pass `"Cookie: ".session_name()."=".session_id();` in the headers. This will essentially make the server hijack your own session to keep the authentication that you provided.

Comment: You can specify headers using `stream_context_create()`. The `curl` extension is nice, yes. However, there are rare cases were it is really required.

Comment: Do you have a file that is actually, literally called `cPanel.php?p=create_member`? Didn't think so :p

Comment: So it has a problem with the arguments part, starting from the `?`... yes?

Comment: `file_get_contents` on a local file merely gets the contents of that file. It doesn't process them at all, so you'd just get the raw PHP. Calling it with `localhost`, though, will fetch the result instead.

Comment: Why should they access this file remotely instead of redirecting to this part of user panel? What's the point in fetching contents of that page and showing them on current page when a normal behavior would be to redirect the user to the desired page

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky In this case, it doesn't seem to make much sense. However, this answer can be applied to similar applications, where you might wish to call a remote API on behalf of a user.

Answer (score 0):

> even though I am logged in.

I'm not sure if you really are.

But it is possible to process a real login via PHP. After that, you should be able to access the correct data.

Two examples that might be useful:

[Using Authentication And file_get_contents()](http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/using-authentication-and-filegetcontents)

[file_get_contents from url that is only accessible after log-in to website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082302/file-get-contents-from-url-that-is-only-accessible-after-log-in-to-website)

Comment: Yep, Niet the Dark Absol got it right below. Thanks for replying :)